# Error in RStudio with read.table(url...)

Tags: r, url, rstudio

I tried to run the code below in RStudio, it always returns the error message of connection failure. It works in RGui. Any idea why this is and how to fix it? Is it problem with my Rstudio (I'm running Windows 8)?

```
survey <- read.table(url("ftp://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"), 
                header=FALSE, sep=",", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The FTP session was terminated
b'
```

Alternative code I have tried:

```
survey <- read.table(url('ftp://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data'), 
                header=FALSE, sep=",", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

survey <- read.table('ftp://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data', 
                header=FALSE, sep=",", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Might need to edit your .REnviron file. Read this https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-Proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RStudio and RGUI may be using different defaults for `setInternet2()`, so try running `setInternet2(use=FALSE)` at the beginning of your session.

Here is an explanation from RStudio (2013):

> Also we call `setInternet2(use=TRUE)` on startup which takes proxy
>   settings from Internet Explorer to make proxies work in the majority
>   of cases. We also have an open bug to allow users to turn this off on
>   startup, but **for now you'll have to call setInternet2(use=FALSE)
>   manually for each session**. For more information on the command, call
>   the following from the console: `?setInternet2()`

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200657716-Rstudio-with-aproxy

For Windows, you may have the option to turn this off within RStudio, as someone with Windows mentioned the solution below (2014):

> One solution was to **go to Tools > Global Options > Packages, and
>   unselect "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP"**.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201327633-Bug-report-RStudio-causes-download-file-to-fail-with-FTP-downloads